# Python import function/class using full path or base path

Tags: python, import

What is recommended when importing something from a subpackage?

Option A:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing

train_test_split()
preprocessing()
```

Option B:

```
import sklearn

sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split()
sklearn.preprocessing()
```

In my opinion, using option A you may not know where the function comes from when you see it many lines after it is imported. In option B, you always know where it comes from because it is more verbose. However, you always need to write the full path function. Is that a disadvantage?

What are your recommendations?

Comment: Moreover, is there an official name for what I call base path (option B)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is "recommended" as a general best practice but I guess every organization could have their own guidelines for this.

In case of your question of wanting to know where the function is called from but not having to write out the full function call every time I could suggest using from -> import -> as, and giving the function a descriptive name.

Then when you start typing it out you get auto-complete suggestion for the full name and it makes writing faster.

Exmple

```
from os.path import join as os_path_join

os_path_join("path_a", "path_b")
```

Answer (score 0):

We generally used option A. It is also good practice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into `importlib`. It is a package that allows you to import a function, class, variable or whatever from any existing location / package / module.

Here is an example using it to import a function from a full path:

```
sum = importlib.import_module("package.module.submodule.sum")
total = sum(1, 2)
```

You can also import an entire file and use any declaration found within it:

```
submodule = importlib.import_module("package.module.submodule")
sum = getattr(submodule, 'sum')
total = sum(1, 2)
```

Hope this helps. I saw the solutions of other contributors and none of them mentioned this library so I thought this might be helpful for someone.